# DynamoDB, method to paginate 100,000 documents with offset/limit?

Tags: java, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have 100,000 documents successfully stored in a table. Currently, I'm just using a primary key (not hash/sort combo). There's no good way to split these into useful partitions for reads, because primarily customers will just be initially pulling the entire database, and then just pulling whatever items have been updated. Additionally, I would like to return results in a paginated fashion using an offset/limit method.

I'm wondering what the best way to do this is. An example item that I have stored in the table is like (id is the primary key):

```
{
        "id": 11299,
        "name": "plugin1",
        "attributes": {
            "plugin_version": "1.30",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "risk_factor": "Medium",
            "plugin_type": "remote",
            "exploitability_ease": "No known exploits are available",
            "plugin_publication_date": "2003-03-01T00:00:00Z",
            "plugin_modification_date": "2018-07-16T00:00:00Z",
            "vuln_publication_date": "2003-01-23T00:00:00Z"
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "raw": "E:U/RL:OF/RC:C",
                "ReportConfidence": "Confirmed",
                "Exploitability": "Unproven",
                "RemediationLevel": "Official-fix"
            }
        }
    }
```

I also need to filter on `plugin_modification_date`, so not sure if it would be helpful to make that a sort key. What's been frustrating when investigating this so far is that everything seems to rely on using the partition key somehow, where it is basically useless when you have a solitary primary key which is unique for all items.

Comment: DynamoDB isn’t well suited for offset/limit pagination because either you need to give the items unique sequential numbers (and maintain the numbers as items are added and removed) or else you need to read items 0..N-1 just to know which item is the Nth item. Furthermore, the ordering of a scan is not guaranteed to be consistent between calls.